# How to avoid parallel execution within a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure that should processes data for a certain day and fill a history table. But if the data for that day has already been processed, i.e. if there is any single row for that certain date in the history table, it should abort:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
IF EXISTS (
  select *
  from history_table
  where convert(date, call_time) = @date_to_process
) 
THROW 50000, N'This day has already been processed. Exiting!', 1;

// process the data ... 

// fill the history table 
insert into history_table (call_time, other_data)
select call_time, other_data
from #processed_data;
```

Sometimes when I call the SP with a `@date_to_process` that has definitely not been processed before, I still get the error "*This day has already been processed. Exiting!*". But when I look at the history table, I see that the insert statement actually ran. I doubt that those two statements run sequentially. It looks like the INSERT statement finishes **before** the existence check.

How can I make sure that those run sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to use an `ELSE` so that only one statement is executed:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

IF EXISTS (select null
           from history_table
           where convert(date, call_time) = @date_to_process
          )
    THROW 50000, N'This day has already been processed. Exiting!', 1;

ELSE // fill the history table 
    insert into history_table (call_time, other_data)
    select call_time, other_data
    from #processed_data;
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried that. But strangely enough it still happens.

Comment: There is no way for an `IF` statement to execute both the `IF` and the `ELSE`.  You are either running this procedure multiple times or your overall data processing pattern is not suitable.  For example, are you purging the `#processing_data` table fully before each execution?  If you could actually provide an example with some dummy data that replicates this issue, you will get a more helpful response.